# Visual studio wrong contextual error message

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using vs2017 latest build. Sometimes when I changed my code in debug mode, vs shows a red squiggly underline, without any reason. I should close and reopen the vs to remove the wrong errors, but now these errors still exist.
Sorry for my bad English. The picture explains my mean:

[image: Wrong error underlines]

How can I refresh / reset the editor to clear the wrong errors?
Thanks

Comment: "Latest build" is enough to explain this kind of misery.  VS2017 is not getting tested anymore, they depend on users doing it for them.  The agile way.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.  Just in case, don't let too many syntax errors build up.  The compiler can lose its marbles when it has to parse code that is too broken.  But of course restarting VS should not have any affect on that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't refresh or reset the IDE. You build your project and if there are any errors in your code, including at the underlined spot, they show up in the "Error List" window. Then you work them out and build again. Repeat this procedure until there are no errors in the "Error List". During this procedure, any false positives - e.g. red underline - should be gone. Even if they exist, but the error list is empty, your program is doing fine.

If you don't see the "Error List", you display it on the "View -> Error List" or through the shortcut "Ctrl + \,E".